# Apply function on dataset before using dataset in other function in Excel or Spreadsheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have the following function:

```
=MAX(LEN(B5),LEN(C5),LEN(D5),LEN(E5))
```

To make it a bit more dynamic, I was hoping to have a function that could apply a function on a dataset before passing it to another function.

Something like this:

```
=MAX(FUNCTION_I_AM_LOOKING_FOR(B5:E5, LEN))
```

Does this exist? Or how would you solve this?

Here is an example. I want to avoid that if 10 languages are added, I have to modify the function too much.

[image]

Comment: Maybe an actual sample with data could clarify what you are after. Also, it's either Excel or Google Sheets. What are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am using Google Sheets, but I do not really care too much if it is Excel or Google Sheets. I am curious if there is a solution out there.
I will add a simplified sample.

Comment: So you are looking for `=MAX(LEN(B2:E2))`?

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't work, because LEN can only take a string as argument. Not a dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ExcelO365:

```
=MAX(LEN(B2:E2))
```

In older version of Excel you'd have to enter through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

In Google Sheets:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(LEN(B2:E2)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So I was looking for this ARRAYFORMULA function. Didn't know this. Perfect.